# Drupal 8 - Can I remove old prefixed tables?

Tags: database, drupal, drupal-8

I have more tables prefixed by "old_" in drupal 8 database.

[image]

Probably herited from an old minor drupal 8 version. 
I am currently in drupal 8.8.5.
I need to clean my database to get more free space for performance optimization reason.
Can I remove these tables? Do i need migration stuff or should left some of them or can i remove all of them ^^?

Thank you

Comment: another issue has been created in https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3128499

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. These were probably created when Drupal was updated to version 8.7 or later, because menus and taxonomy terms became revisionable in that release.

It is recommended to take backups of the tables before you drop them, just in case there is a problem.

More information in [this post on Drupal Answers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/282737/additional-old-xxxxxxtaxonomy-term-field-xxx-tables-after-upgrading). That is a better Stack Exchange site for asking Drupal-sepcific questions.